# Array in PHP Dealing with multiple types

Tags: php, arrays

I may have the following types of arrays:

```
array(
  'key' => array(),
   array(),
)
```

or ...

```
array(
  'key' => array(),
  'key' => value
)
```

and essentially I am looking to do something like:

```
foreach($array as $something){
  // if $something has a key
     // do something
  // if $something is an array
     // do something
}
```

Whats the cleanest and most OOP way to handle this type of issue?

Comment: Of issue? What issue? You haven't explained any

Answer (score 0):

The code you have supplied has nothing to do with OOP but judging by the comments in your code you may want to look at [is_array()](https://www.php.net/is_array) and [isset()](https://www.php.net/isset)